# C# Obsolete method with navigator to new method

Tags: c#, visual-studio, intellisense

Is it possible to add the new method to the obsolete method attribute, so if someone types the obsolete one the new one will pop-up?

Like with List.Length that navigates to Count, or is it vs that does this?

Comment: Not with the attribute. You could do something with a code analyser, but it's probably just easier to add a good description to the attribute message.

Comment: You mean like in the Examples here: [ObsoleteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=net-5.0)?

Comment: Also worth noting that there is no `List.Length` property, not even an obsolete one.

Comment: @DavidG if I type in new List<int>(). Length is an option but when I select it it changes to Count. This could be resharper doing this.

Comment: Yes, almost certainly Resharper doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you cannot get that you want in **VS IDE**. And your idea is from **Resharper Intellisense**.

**In fact**, VS IDE has abandoned the obsolete variables, attributes, and so on. You can not find them on **VS IDE**. And only **Resharper Intellisense** remain the old ones and can navigate to the new suggested one automatically by Intellisense.

**However**, you should note that these requirements are for VS default system variables and they are built-in parameters(we cannot change properties,functions like that).

**If** you try the method, properties written by yourself, the only way is to use [ObsoleteAttribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.obsoleteattribute?view=net-5.0). And you have to manually add notes for each obsolete method, and then manually change to a new method according to the IntelliSense prompt.

**And** no matter it is **Resharper** or **VS IDE**, you cannot get the function of replacing obsolete methods automatically by Intellisense.

**In more detail**, Resharper's reminder is more obvious. `Test()` and `Test1()` are custom method written by me and are used `ObsoleteAttribute`.

[image]

**VS IDE** is:

[image]

**Suggestion**

**If** you still get what you want(add an automatic replacement function for custom obsolete properties, methods), you should [suggest a feature on our DC Forum](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/spaces/8/index.html).

[image]

**And** when you finishing the ticket, you can share the link here and anyone who is interested in it including us will vote it.

**With** all of these, I think it will get more attention from Microsoft to help us deal with it more quickly.

Answer (score 0):

No. You should provide a good description message with instructions on how to rewrite the code. The ObsoleteAttribute is a message to developers that the code they are using needs to be updated, and this usually need intervention by a developer to ensure the change does not affect the behavior.

It might be possible to create a new attribute and some tooling to update the source code according information in the attribute. But if you need such functionality you would need to implement it yourself. My guess is that it might be a bit complex to handle various edge cases.